# groovy matcher failing or returning single characters and not whole words

Tags: regex, indexing, groovy, character

I am attempting to create a matcher to match a regex and return a particular index, but despite trying numerous variations of the code, it either throws an exception, or only prints single characters and not the whole word.  All of the examples I find are similar to what I am doing, but my results don't look like the examples.  Here's the code:

```
def RAW = """
        policer-profile "GD-1" 
            bandwidth cir 4992 cbs 32767 eir 4992 ebs 32767 
            traffic-type all 
            compensation 0 
        exit
        policer-profile "EIR-1" 
            bandwidth cir 0 cbs 0 eir 9984 ebs 32767 
            traffic-type all 
            compensation 0 
        exit
        shaper-profile "Shaper1" 
            bandwidth cir 999936 cbs 65535 
            compensation 0 
        exit
"""

RAW.split("\n").each() { line ->
   def matcher = line =~ /bandwidth cir \d+ cbs \d+/
   if (matcher) {
      println line[0][2]
   }
}
```

I keep getting either "index out of range" or it simply prints the "n" (third character) in the word "bandwidth" for each line, instead of the numerical value after "cir" (the third word).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried adding .* to the end, and now it doesn't appear to match anything - I used [regexr](http://regexr.com) to test it with the grouping of (line =~ /regex/) and it works there, but groovy console doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: I still get nothing when using that code, might it be my version of groovy console or something?  I have 2.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sligthly modified the script:

```
def RAW = """
        policer-profile "GD-1" 
            bandwidth cir 4992 cbs 32767 eir 4992 ebs 32767 
            traffic-type all 
            compensation 0 
        exit
        policer-profile "EIR-1" 
            bandwidth cir 0 cbs 0 eir 9984 ebs 32767 
            traffic-type all 
            compensation 0 
        exit
        shaper-profile "Shaper1" 
            bandwidth cir 999936 cbs 65535 
            compensation 0 
        exit
"""

RAW.split("\n").each() { line ->
   def matcher = line =~ /\s+bandwidth cir (\d+) cbs (\d+).*/
   if(matcher.matches()) {
      println "cir: ${matcher[0][1]}, cbs: ${matcher[0][2]}"
   }
}
```

You had an mistaken regex (whitespace at the beginning as well as not matching the end of line) and remember to output groups taken from `matcher` not from `line`. Now it should work.

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  I'll get this matcher stuff one of these days - it seems like my problems usually stem from a bad regex.  Is that normally the case?

Comment: It might be. If there's a problem use regex, there will be another one :). Please accept ;)